# Integration testing with mongojs to cover database errors

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, mongojs

I'm working with `mongojs` and writing tests for `mocha` running coverage with `istanbul`. My issue is that I would like to include testing db errors.

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs.connect(/* connection string */);
var collection = db.collection('test');

...
rpc.register('calendar.create', function(/*... */) {
    collection.update({...}, {...}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            // this code should be tested
            return;
        }

        // all is good, this is usually covered
    });
});
```

the test looks like this

```
it("should gracefully fail", function (done) {

    /* trigger db error by some means here */

    invoke("calendar.create", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            // check that the error is what we expect
            return done();
        }

        done(new Error('No expected error in db command.'));
    });
});
```

There is a fairly complex setup script that sets up the integration testing environment. The current solution is to disconnect the database using `db.close()` and run the test resulting in an error as wanted. The problem with this solution arises when all the other tests after that require the database connection fail, as I try to reconnect without success.

Any ideas on how to solve this neatly? Preferably without writing custom errors that might not be raised by next version of `mongojs`. Or is there a better way of structuring the tests?

Answer (score 0):

What about mocking the library that deals with mongo?

For example, assuming `db.update` is eventually the function that gets called by `collection.update` you might want to do something like

```
describe('error handling', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(db, 'update').yields('error');  
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    // db.update will just error for the scope of this test
    db.update.restore();
  });

  it('is handled correctly', function() {
    // 1) call your function

    // 2) expect that the error is logged, dealt with or 
    // whatever is appropriate for your domain here
  });

});
```

I've used [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) which is

> Standalone test spies, stubs and mocks for JavaScript. No dependencies, works with any unit testing framework.

Does this make sense?

Comment: It does make sense. However, I was kind of hoping for some built-in error triggering, which would simulate a range of actual errors. I'll just let this question hang around for a little while longer, before I accept this as an answer, but thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I see that @AndreasNiedermair edited my question to remove the reference to mongojs, to the more generic case of just testing, which in this case might not really be what I was after. I guess my problem is not as common as I expected.

Comment: I think that if you're trying to test for error handling the easiest way is to mock and have an error returned to you, but it's just IMHO... I don't know your scenario.