# how to mock mongo update error when use sinon

Tags: mongodb, sinon

ref: [Integration testing with mongojs to cover database errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120905/integration-testing-with-mongojs-to-cover-database-errors/29121096#29121096)

the scene of link is as same as mine - integration test with mongoskin to cover db errors.

```
var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
var db = require('./setting').DB;
var collection = db.collection('test');
var route = require('express').Router();

...
route.post('test', function(req,res) {
    db.collection('test').update({...}, {...}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            // this code should be tested
            logger.error(err);
            return;
        }

        // all is good, this is usually covered
    });
});
```

file.test.js

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var rewire = require('rewire');
var tc = rewire('./file');
var superagent = require('superagent');
var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
var db = tc.__get__('db');

it('xx', function(done){
    var update = sinon.stub().yields(new Error('error'));
    sinon.stub(db, 'collection').returns({update: update})

    superagent.post(url).send(data).end(function(e,res){
        done();
    });
})
```

I try it but invalid.

Help. I hope to mock update of mongodb and set error to the 3rd arg, logger output the scream.